# Mag 2.2.3 After Add/Update importing do not change nothing

Tags: product, import, upgrade, magento2.2.3

i have the products in my site Magento 2.2.3, after a importation add/Update, that products don't change value (Product name ecc....).
i edit and modify any value of this product but what i change i can not see it.
Cache and index i update after this change, but nothing happens in admin view and on-lin view.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem with the import process. How did you do it? Have you used the third party extension? It's better to do it with [Data Migration Tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool.html), as mentioned in the documentation. The tool can import your data automatically. So, the value of the products will change accordingly.

Comment: i have used system import product of Magento with Add/Update option, to update with CSV someone existing product. Check is ok, import product is ok. But when i change in admin product list product name, not work. All modification when edit this product, is saved but not workint.